# MediaPlayer delays more than 20 seconds trying to open a non-existent url

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

My app uses `MediaPlayer` to play audio files from our CDN.

It's not the typical situation, but sometimes the file might not exist.

In that case, the CDN (AWS CloudFront-based) returns a `403 - Forbidden` HTTP status code (please see attached response dump).

This seems to annoy `MediaPlayer`, and enters a loop of 10 delayed retries before triggering an error event. The problem is, the Java application does not have a clue on what's going on until the whole process ends.

I don't know if this is a bug in `MediaPlayer`, not handling the `403-Forbidden` code as a fatal error, or this is done for a reason, as this happens at least in Android 5, 6 and 7, the ones I've tried.

Have you faced this problem? Is there any workaround? Should I file a bug to Android ?

in my app, this is what happens after calling prepareAsync() for a non-existent file:

```
04-04 06:48:16.555 327-5110/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 7 retries left
04-04 06:48:19.697 327-5110/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 6 retries left
04-04 06:48:22.779 327-5110/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 5 retries left
04-04 06:48:25.861 327-5110/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 4 retries left
04-04 06:48:28.946 327-5110/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 3 retries left
04-04 06:48:32.030 327-5110/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 2 retries left
04-04 06:48:35.101 327-5110/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 1 retries left
04-04 06:48:38.166 327-5110/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 0 retries left
```

note the above retries took 20 seconds, then the error is reported back to the app.

```
04-04 06:48:38.245 327-5105/? V/FFmpegExtractor: SniffFFMPEG
04-04 06:48:38.245 327-5105/? I/FFmpegExtractor: android-source:0xf1ae2120
04-04 06:48:38.245 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: android source begin open
04-04 06:48:38.245 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: android open, url: android-source:0xf1ae2120
04-04 06:48:38.245 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: ffmpeg open android data source success, source ptr: 0xf1ae2120
04-04 06:48:38.245 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: android source open success
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: android source close
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? E/FFmpegExtractor: android-source:0xf1ae2120: avformat_open_input failed, err:Operation not permitted
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? W/FFmpegExtractor: sniff through BetterSniffFFMPEG failed, try LegacySniffFFMPEG
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? I/FFmpegExtractor: source url:http://????.io/juanin/story/nuit/lib/page12/audio.mp3
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: android source begin open
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: android open, url: android-source:0xf1ae2120|file:http://????.io/juanin/story/nuit/lib/page12/audio.mp3
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: ffmpeg open android data source success, source ptr: 0xf1ae2120
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: android source open success
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? D/FFMPEG: android source close
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? E/FFmpegExtractor: android-source:0xf1ae2120|file:http://????.io/juanin/story/nuit/lib/page12/audio.mp3: avformat_open_input failed, err:Operation not permitted
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? D/FFmpegExtractor: SniffFFMPEG failed to sniff this source
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5105/? E/GenericSource: Failed to init from data source!
04-04 06:48:38.246 327-5104/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xf1ae2060), (100, 1, -2147483648)
04-04 06:48:38.246 3199-3308/tv.nebular.app.mini E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
04-04 06:48:38.273 3199-3199/tv.nebular.app.mini E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

And the response (403):

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 1545
Cache-Control: public,max-age=30672000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 524
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 04 Apr 2018 10:45:45 GMT
ETag: "6f8a9f263707ea54eb529ecfcd24ee65"
Last-Modified: Sat, 18 Nov 2017 17:26:22 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Via: 1.1 xxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: Yu-Y_bKySz9GsKwnmkdd3E7J76c8h6kAGkqpeNr9Cd2i3pjihknajg==
x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs: uid:501/gname:staff/xxx/gid:20/mode:33188/mtime:1511022859/atime:1511022859/md5:6f8a9f263707ea54eb529ecfcd24ee65/ctime:1511022859
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
```

Comment: Maybe try manually hitting the URL and verify if the file exists, before firing up the MediaPlayer? Just a quick workaround, although may be n overhead!

Comment: that's probably the best thing to do, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Your example of a 403 response is clearly a custom error page -- not standard behavior.  What if you change that custom error page to actually set the error code to 404 rather than 403?

Comment: There are reasons for that, and we unfortunately cannot change the CDN.